# How to get a screenshot via display android in android

Tags: java, android

I need to get a screenshot of when the application is minimized

This code a grab screenshot from `rootView` of application activity:

```java
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap original = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

How to get a screenshot from the display, and not from the activity view?

Comment: Please Define display.  I mean do you want some part of your activity ?

Comment: I think op is talking about [Display](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display), whole screen, even when app is in background

Comment: Yes, I need to receive screenshots even when the application is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

there is an API dedicated for screenshots/recordings called MediaProjection, some doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html)

sample projects in [HERE](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/MediaProjection/andshooter) and [HERE](https://github.com/android/media-samples/tree/main/ScreenCapture)